# Clean Install with Exceptions

Tags: install, macos

My current OS X install is getting long in the tooth. It's been ported over through multiple OS upgrades and system changes (started with an iMac G4, then a PowerMac G5, and now a iMac i7).

I think it's about time to do a clean install to get rid of all the crap that's been accumulated. Is there a way to do a clean install with exceptions? I'd love to keep my applications and application preferences intact, but pretty much start anew with everything else.

I've got Time Machine backups, and would do a SuperDuper copy to an external drive before starting fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Migration Assistant will let you do just what you've asked. [Here is an article](http://www.macworld.com/article/162154/2011/09/move_data_from_an_old_mac_to_a_new_mac.html) on this but it's pretty straightforward.